# TypeScript class with null properties when initializing

Tags: typescript

I have started a new Next.js project with typescript with `npx create-next-app --example with-typescript with-typescript-app` (https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-typescript).

How ever when I try to create a class like this:

```
export class Programm {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    thumbnailUrl: string;
}
```

I get the syntax error:

`Property 'id' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)`

when I add a constructor like this:

```
constructor(id: string, name: string, thumbnailUrl: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}
```

It works. Why is that and how can I create an object so the properties are null when initializing the class?

The same code is working without the constructor in angular

Comment: Read about [Strict class initialization](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-class-initialization)

Comment: Look for tsconfig.json options if you wish to deactivate it

Answer (score 10):

You can define your properties as optional, with a `?` modifier:

```
export class Programm {
     id?: string;
     name?: string;
     thumbnailUrl?: string;
}
```

Now if you initialize a new instance of type "Programm", properties will have `undefined` value.

Comment: Or you can have the type be union with undefined `id: string | undefined;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the below steps
-> Follow @Mr.Jurica Smircic solution then
-> Define Initial Value

```
constructor(id: string, name: string, thumbnailUrl: string) {
    this.id = id || '' ;
    this.name = name || '';
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl || '';
}
```

There are a lot of discussions in the stack over follow why you should not use null or undefined.
They always encourage to define initial values either via the constructor or during the initialization of the objects. for example empty object. For better understanding, you can look at these [Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/120356) threads.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you asked,if you want null values instead of undefined on initialization, you can do this way :

```
export class Programm {
    id: string | null = null;
    name: string | null = null;
    thumbnailUrl: string | null = null;
}
```

```
var programm = new Programm()
console.log(programm)
```

```
>>> Programm: { "id":null, "name":null, "thumbnailUrl":null }
```